# How to make a JTree node auto-expand when it is selected?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Basically I want the tree node's select event to behave like the expand event.

How could I do this?

Comment: cool - what a row about this question. Mere mortal me having been daring enough [to go meta to the gods](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147515/159794) - glad everything panned out in the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`JTree#setExpandsSelectedPaths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setExpandsSelectedPaths%28boolean%29) is what you are looking for

Comment: glad you weren't effected by the storm I blew off at meta :-) To me, yours is a perfect answer, even with a better worded question couldn't have been improved.

Comment: @kleopatra I actually find the current state of the question worse then the original one. Question no longer mentions `JTree`, except for the tag. And it is indeed a simple answer for a simple question if you know the API. If not, you might attempt to add selection listeners and try to expand nodes manually ... a good reason to ask on SO first IMO (but I am not gonna put that on meta ;-) )